# Order of deployed solidity files in etherscan (hardhat.config.js)

Tags: solidity, etherscan, hardhat

How do I choose the order of the solidity files that are deployed please?

I would like my solidity custom file to be deployed before the dependencies (default in Truffle). By default in Hardhat, my custom file is the last one that gets deployed.

Answer (score 0):

To choose the order of the Solidity files that are deployed, you can specify the order in which the files are listed in the contracts array of the Hardhat configuration file (hardhat.config.js). To ensure that your custom file is deployed before the dependencies, you should list it first in the array.

```
module.exports = {
  // other configuration options
  solidity: {
    version: "0.8.0",
    settings: {
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 200,
      },
    },
  },
  contracts: {
    // Custom Solidity file listed first
    myCustomContract: {
      // path to the Solidity file
      path: "./contracts/MyCustomContract.sol",
      // other contract configuration options
    },
    // Other dependencies listed after the custom file
    dependencyContract1: {
      path: "./contracts/DependencyContract1.sol",
      // other contract configuration options
    },
    dependencyContract2: {
      path: "./contracts/DependencyContract2.sol",
      // other contract configuration options
    },
    // more dependencies can be listed here
  },
};
```

Comment: I see this is truffle-config.js configuration. Doesn't work in hardhat :(